# Operation on primes with power $\geq 3$

Tags: number-theory

Question. Can it be shown that if $m, n$ are odd integers $\geq 3$, and with no common factor, then $m^z - n^y = (2^x).K$ where $y, z$ are integers $\geq 3$, $K$ is an odd integer $\geq 3$, and $x$ is a Natural number.

I want to use the proof to show that $m^z - n^y = (2^x)$ with $m,n,y,z$ as defined above and $x$ an integer $\geq 3$, has no solution.

Comment: If you could show $K\ge 3$, then the claim immediately would follow. I do not think, that $K\ge 3$ can be shown easier than proving the claim.

Comment: Please, explicit the quantifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Am new to this site and I don't know how to use MathJax fomula yet

Comment: @Peter thanks for your response. But does it mean I can simply take, without proof, that the claim follows with K>=3?

Comment: Yes, because $K\ge 3$ contradicts $K=1$.